# In the movies, did Voldemort kill Pettigrew after the escape from Malfoy Manor?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, voldemort, adaptation-comparison, death-eaters

What happened to Peter Pettigrew when Harry and the others stunned him and escaped from Malfoy Manor?

In the books, it's told that the silver hand given to him by Voldemort kills Wormtail because he betrays his master, as mentioned here: [Why did the silver hand turn against Wormtail?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37374/why-did-the-silver-hand-turn-against-wormtail)

But in the movies, there is no reference to Wormtail's fate. Was he killed by Voldemort after the escape of Harry and his friends?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Dobby (probably) killed him.

The final mention of Pettigrew in the [original script](https://www.scribd.com/doc/163084623/HARRY-POTTER-AND-THE-DEATHLY-HALLOWS-PART-2-by-screenplay-Steve-Kloves) (and in the film) is when you see him collapse, having been zapped from behind by Dobby.

> [The knob turns and light splashes into the cellar as ...... Wormtail fills the doorway]
>
> [Harry and Ron stiffen, then watch Wormtail fall forward, stiff as a board, tumbling in a heavy heap on the cement floor below. They turn back as Dobby appears, Wormtail’s wand in his tiny fist.]
>
> **DOBBY:** *Who gets his wand?*

In the absence of anything to suggest otherwise, I think we can say that it's *likely* that Dobby killed him.

---

To support this I offer in evidence the fact that only a few minutes after shooting Pettigrew in the back, Dobby is more than happy to try to murder another one of Harry's enemies (*Bellatrix*) by dropping a three-tonne chandelier on their head. He clearly has no compunction about killing people in order to protect his friend Harry, despite his rather feeble protestations that he only meant to injure or maim.

Comment: He says right after dropping the thing that his goal was not to kill, but only to maim or seriously injure.

Comment: @TimE.Lord - I would contend that he's a filthy little liar

Comment: Don't be anti-house-elf! It wouldn't be a great loss if a Death Eater died!

Comment: @HarryWeasley I very much disagree with that! :P

Comment: @Bellatrix Having seen your answers on Stack Exchange, I indeed retract my original statement!

Comment: @HarryWeasley Thanks a lot, it’s nice to know I’m appreciated! ;)

Comment: Disagree. Whether or not Dobby is truthful is irrelevant. It is entirely possible to incapacitate someone and take their wand without killing them, or even intent to kill. Likewise, Dobby dropped that chandelier on Bellatrix _and_ Hermione, mind.

Answer (score 6):

## It’s ambiguous, he’s attacked by Dobby then not seen again.

In the movie, it’s unclear whether Pettigrew died. The last scene he’s in, he’s knocked out by Dobby as Harry, Ron, and Hermione escape from Malfoy Manor.

After that, he isn’t seen or mentioned again, in any way that would make it clear what happened.

Comment: The video is unavailable.